# SimpleXML, xpath doesnt return anything

Tags: php, xpath, simplexml

Trying to do 2 things  using PHP

1) Use xpath() to run an xpath query that picks out all the Product tags. This should return you an array of SimpleXMLElements representing each Product tag.

2) Use xpath() again to select from each Product tag the ProductCode and ProductName and get their contents.

My XML is

```
<All_Products>
<Product>
<ProductCode>9978H</ProductCode>
<ProductName>abc with Buckle in aBlack</ProductName>
<ProductURL>http://abc.com/abc with Buckle in aBlack-p/9978H.htm<ProductURL>
<StockStatus>2</StockStatus>
</Product>
<Product>
<ProductCode>99s</ProductCode>
<ProductName>abc with Buckle in aBlack</ProductName>
<ProductURL>http://abc.com/abc with Buckle in aBlack-p/9978H.htm</ProductURL>
<StockStatus>2</StockStatus>
</Product>
</All_Products>
```

My PHP code looks like below but its not returning any product tags, product code etc, what is the problem in my code

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('http://www.abc.com/xml.php');


if ($xml === false) {
    echo 'Error while parsing the document';
    exit;
}

$dom_sxe = dom_import_simplexml($xml);
if (!$dom_sxe) {
    echo 'Error while converting XML';
    exit;
}


$result = $xml->xpath('/All_Products/Product');

while(list( , $node) = each($result)) {
    echo '/a/b/c: ',$node,"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your XML is not valid - "ProductURL" tag is not closed.
Secondly "$node" will be an object, so you can't print it that way.

Comment: yes i will close that producturl tag so what is the best method to solve my problem